# Remove some text from a var in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following text in a var-

```
<option value="1">A</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
```

Is there any way to remove any ... block from that by its value? 
i.e. I would like to remove ... where its value is 3. Please note that, above text is in a variable.

I know that i can remove option value from a select as follows:

```
$("#selectBox option[value='option1']").remove();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You could use RegEx to find option with the the value and the remove part of the string by offset and length

Comment: try `$(x).wrapAll('<select />').parent().find('option[value="1"]').remove().end().html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var el =$('<select></select>').append('<option value="1">A</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>')
el.find("option[value='3']").remove();
$('div').append(el)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6cXCJ/1/)

Comment: yeap, exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery filter function. http://api.jquery.com/filter/
This should give you more control of the data you want to process.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.not()` function :

```
var html='<option value="1">A</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>';
html=$(html).not('[value="3"]');
console.log(html);
```

`html` is now

```
<option value=​"1">​A​</option>​
<option value=​"2">​2​</option>​
<option value=​"4">​4​</option>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Using RegEx:

```
var num = 3;
var pattern = new RegExp('<option value="'+num+'">.+?<\/option>', 'i');

var options = '<option value="1">A</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>';

options = options.replace(pattern, '');
console.log(options);
```